# How to check for null in Dart?

Tags: dart

I don't know what I am doing wrong. I thought that to check whether a variable `x` is *not* `null` in Dart, one could simply do `x != null`. But that does not work in this code below. And, it is not clear to me why. I would appreciate why it is not working.

```
void getUserAnswers() {

  HttpRequest.getString(pathToUserAns).then((String data) {

    print("data is: $data");

    if (data != null) {
      print("data is not null");
    }

  });
}
```

The above code gives the following output in the chromium console:

```
data is: null

data is not null
```

which does not seem to make sense.

Comment: The check is correct. I assume that `data` actually is **not** `null` but a string `"null"`. To check you could try `if (data != 'null') {`

Comment: I tried that too. But the second statement still prints.

Comment: try `print("data is: $data, ${data.runtimeType}");`

Comment: See also https://dartpad.dartlang.org/1a72a523fb1ae492a21ef3ed238bc1ef

Comment: It prints: data is: null, String. That is, data's type is String. However, it is not `null`, "null", or ""? What is it then? I will check the dartpad. Thank you for trying to debug this.

Comment: Try `print("data is: x$datax");` I guess there is one or more trailing spaces.

Comment: If I do it like that, it says `No top-level getter or setter 'datax' declared.` I tried `print("data is: x${data}x");` That does print the second `x` on the next line. Does it mean there is a newline character after "null"? If so, how to check if there is no data in a get request? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. Glad you figured it out. It definitely looks like there is a newline at the end. At first it would be interesting where `null\n` value comes from. Seems this needs to be fixed on the server. If this is not possible, you can check for `if(data != null && data.startsWith('null')) {` or similar.

Comment: I will check on the server. I have a Go backend. I printed the data that I was encoding into JSON on the sever using fmt.Println. It printed `[]` as expected, since there are no records to send as of now. I should try to print the JSON encoded value to and see what it gives on the server.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks for your help. It turns out a that my Go backend was sending a string with null, instead of a string of json with empty array. It has to do with how slices are created (declaring them vs using make).

Comment: I would suggest in such cases print out runtime type of received object. For example

    print("data is: $data of type ${data.runtimeType}");

You would get output: data is: null of type String, that make things more obvious. I do it myself frequently